# Changing the VM memory size and Windows Activation

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machines, activation

How often am I allowed to change the memory size for a Windows 7 VM (guest) before it requires reactivation?

Other than using Snapshots - is it possible to make Windows 7 aware that it's running inside a VM and ignore changes to the memory size for Product Activation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware JUST changing memory allocation won't trigger a W7 reactivation request as it requires two hardware changes to instigate that.

Comment: When I change the memory size and then change it again the next day, will that count as just one change? Is there some way to view this change counter?

Comment: It's changes from baseline, i.e. if JUST memory is changed from the baseline (when you activated) you'll be fine, whereas you won't if you change more than two key components.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an issue - I'm running Windows 2008 and 2008R2 servers in VMs, both of which would require activation, and I'm not seeing requests for activation from memory changes.

Comment: Are you running in VMware or Virtual PC? How often have you changed the memory size?

Comment: Oh, VMWare ESX.

I can't give you a hard figure but quite a lot on some servers where we were trying to balance memory loads well for SQL servers to perform acceptably without glomming up lots of resources on a host that could be better used for other things, especially as we wanted to use VMotion and the like. Easily 6 times or more on a couple of guest servers over 2 - 3 days.